# PHP sum of votes and rewarding extra point to a winner

Tags: php

Can any one please help me with the code? Here is the error I am getting,  "Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed" I want the output to print the total votes including the extra 1 point given to the winner, and finally print the result of votes including the extra vote given for the winner in the form.

```
1|4
2|3
3|6
4|3
5|9
```

Here is the form and code:

```
<form action="voting.php" method="get">

Choose your candidate:

<select name="candidate">

<option value=1 selected>1</option>        

<option value=2>2</option>

<option value=3>3</option>

<option value=4>4</option>

<option value=5>5</option>

</select>

<br>

<input type="submit" value="Send">                  

</form>



<?php
$inputs = file('results.txt');
$sum = 0 ;
$res = array();

foreach ($inputs as $line) {
  $var = explode('|', $line);
  $res[$var[0]] = $var[1];
  $add= $add +  $var[1];
}
$fin=array();
$maxVotes=max($res);
foreach ($res as $candidate => $voteCount) {
  if ($voteCount == $maxVotes) {
     $res[$candidate]++;
  $fin=$candidate . "|" . $res[$candidate];


  }
}
$final = implode("\n", $fin);
$fp = fopen('results.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $final);
fclose($fp);
echo "Total votes casted: ",$add+1," votes.";
$file = 'results.txt';
readfile($file);
?>
```

Comment: you declare fin as an array then redeclare it as a string $fin=$candidate . "|" . $res[$candidate]; .. therefore it is no longer an array and cant be passed to implode

Comment: a data base would make this a million times easer

Answer (score 0):

I'm also guessing you want to be appending the result to the fin array not overwriting it with a string, you can do that with

`$fin[] = $candidate . "|" . $res[$candidate];`

Comment: No I actually want to overwrite it with the new results. So when I tried the error is gone but it is only printing the first row.